# Variety that surjects onto curve contains curve that surjects

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective irreducible variety, and let $C$ be an irreducible projective curve, both smooth over a characteristic $0$ algebraically closed field. Let
$$f : X\to C$$
be a surjective morphism. Is there a smooth curve $C'$ contained in $X$, which surjects onto $C$ via $f$?

My professor told me to consider hyperplane sections $H\cap X$ to reduce the dimension. Indeed, the image of an irreducible component of $H\cap X$ is either a single point, or the whole curve $C$.

Since the fiber of a closed point $c\in C$ is of codimension at least $1$, we can choose a hyperplane section not contained in $f^{-1}(c)$, which maps onto several different points of $C$ (we just need that it meet two different fibers). However, the hyperplane section can be composed of different irreducible components, so this does not prove that its image is $C$.

If I could show that the fiber of the generic point $\eta$ of $Y$ meets a generic hyperplane section of $X$, then I would have the result since $f$ is a map between projective varieties, hence proper, so its image is closed, so if it contains $\eta$, it contains its closure, hence $C$.

However, I can't seem to make any progress on this problem even with Bertini's theorems. Can you help me?

Comment: An ample divisor in $X$ cannot be contained in a fiber of $f$ (assuming that the dimension of $X$ is at least 2).

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still learning. I don't understand how to prove what you are saying, or what it says about the problem. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: An ample divisor has positive intersection with any curve, but a divisor contained in a fiber of $f4 does not intersect (hence has zero intersection with) any curve contained in another fiber.

Comment: If you have no smoothness hypothesis, why can't you take $X=C$, a singular curve to get a counterexample?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the smoothness hypothesis. X and C are both smooth.